# Connecting GCP Snowflake to Airflow certificate issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are trying to connect to the snowflake instance using snowflake-sqlalchemy library (latest version).

```
Getting next error:
[2020-09-28 14:47:47,558] {{connection.py:409}} WARNING - Certificate did not match expected hostname: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.snowflakecomputing.com. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', '*.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com'),),), 'subjectAltName': [('DNS', '*.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com'), ('DNS', '*.snowflakecomputing.com'), ('DNS', '*.global.snowflakecomputing.com'), ('DNS', '*.prod1.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com'), ('DNS', '*.prod2.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com'), ('DNS', '*.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com')]}
```

Seems like the certificates for the snowflake instance do not match the host.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

This is on a trial account if that matters.

Comment: Can you login to the webUI?  e.g. https://xxxxxxx.europe-west4.snowflakecomputing.com    These cert issues are not typical and might require you to reach out to support for help.

Comment: Yes can login to UI ok just not connect through airflow

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Suzy Lockwood, the domain being generated is wrong.  The reason it ends up pointing to `*.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com` is because the target, lacking the `gcp` or `azure` ends up getting a redirect to `us-west-2`, where (of course) the certificate is wrong for what was expected.

The solution (for me) turned out to be that region needs the `.azure` suffix, not just the region. I'd given it that information under 'account' - I'm not sure if the presence of the region parameter got in the way, or if both are needed.  But, it is working now, and I'm loathe to touch it more today. :)

Comment: I spent hours on this, and this turned out to finally do it for me. THANK YOU! I can't believe I couldn't find this answer sooner... Does nobody use Snowflake in Azure on Airflow? Didn't think this would be a super uncommon problem. Nonetheless, thank you for posting!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Region needed to be `east-us-2.azure` in Airflow Connections.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed europe-west4.  Is that a GCP account? If so, I think your URL/hostname is supposed to look like this, but you can double-check in the UI:

XXXXX.europe-west4.GCP.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: Thanks Suzy, thats a good spot, the host name is set as XXXXX.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com, but the warning is returned for xxxxxxx.europe-west4.snowflakecomputing.com, I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

The airflow snowflake objects are built for AWS, and not compatible for GCP so I will need to find GCP versions or create GCP compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you would [solve the issue](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/snowflake-data-ingestion-custom-operator-airflow-pradip-wawge/?articleId=6673875610986803200). The account name should also contain the gcp. as shown in the article above

```
{
"account":"xxxxx.us-central1.gcp",

"warehouse":"COMPUTE_WH",

"region":"us-central1",

"database":"CITIBIKE",

"schema":"PUBLIC"

}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I have account including region and .gcp, however I'm still getting same error... the hostname includes the "*.gcp*" but on the built path I don't see ".gcp" included and that's why it does not match... I don't find a way to make it match with the given params